# How to deny access at specify country and allow only with password authentication via .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, ip, .htaccess

I need to deny access on a website at a specific country, but allow to bypass via .htaccess authentication

I found this website
https://www.ip2location.com/blockvisitorsbycountry.aspx

where I can download an .htaccess that deny access from a specific country, but I'm not sure if is possible to add the ability to proceed with a user / password

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 123.456.789.0/255 
</Limit>
```

placing this in root folder would also deny access to Google Robots outside that country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the 'satisfy' directive?:

> The Satisfy directive can be used to specify that several criteria may
>   be considered when trying to decide if a particular user will be
>   granted admission. Satisfy can take as an argument one of two options
>   - all or any. By default, it is assumed that the value is all. This means that if several criteria are specified, then all of them must be
>   met in order for someone to get in. However, if set to any, then
>   several criteria may be specified, but if the user satisfies any of
>   these, then they will be granted entrance.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html#satisfy

Comment: it seems to work